# Jump test in Jasmine in a unit

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I would like to know if there exists something in Jasmine like @ignore in JUnit.
I would like to ignore some tests, but not all.

I'm refering something like this:

```
@Ignore
describe("Hello world", function() {
  it("says hello", function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jasmine docs:

> Suites can be disabled with the xdescribe function. These suites and any specs inside them are skipped when run and thus their results will show as pending.

Source: https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Disabling_Suites

Answer (score 3):

You can prefix either the `describe` or `it` blocks with `x` and they will be disabled. So in effect you are calling `xdescribe` or `xit`.

```
xdescribe("Hello world", function() {
  it("says hello", function() {
    expect(helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!! Using "xit", this is my output: Results: 13 specs, 0 failures, 1 pending